# Can't create email labels & filters via Google Apps for Work API

Tags: php, curl, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

I need to be able to programmatically set email filters (something that gmail API doesn't support), so...

I signed up today for a Google apps for Work 30 days trial, I read the [docs over here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_labels) and I found this **PHP code** (adapted for my needs, code running on a dedicated box running PHP Version 5.4.30 + CentOS 6.4):

```
<?php

$user_email  = 'super-admin@my-domain.com';
$user_passwd = 'admin-password';
$email_label = 'my-label';

// ================================================================== //
function getEmailXML($is_label)
{
    global $user_email, $email_label;

    list($username, $domain) = split('@', $user_email);

    $result = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" . "\n";

    if ($is_label)
    {
        $result .= "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>";
        $result .= "<apps:property name=\"label\" value=\"$email_label\" />";
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>";
        $result .= "    <apps:property name='to' value='$username+$email_label@$domain' />";
        $result .= "    <apps:property name='label' value='$email_label' />";
        $result .= "    <apps:property name='neverSpam' value='true' />";
    }

    $result .= "</atom:entry>";

    return $result;
} 

// ================================================================== //
function getAuthToken($account)
{
    // Getting the google authentication token

    $tk_ch     = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $account);

    curl_setopt($tk_ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        true);

    $response  = curl_exec($tk_ch);

    curl_close($tk_ch);

    $str_split = split('=', $response);
    $token     = $str_split[3];

    return $token;
} 

// ================================================================== //
function email_New_Filter_Or_Label($token, $action)
{
    global $user_email;
    list($username, $domain) = split('@', $user_email);

    $ch       = curl_init();
    $url_feed = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/$domain/$username/$action";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url_feed);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,    true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array(
        'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="' . trim($token) . '"',
        'Content-type: application/atom+xml'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, getEmailXML(($action == 'label')));    // getEmailXML($is_label)
    $result   = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
// ================================================================== //

$my_acc     = array(
    'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
    'Email'       => $user_email,
    'Passwd'      => $user_passwd,
    'service'     => 'apps',
);

$auth_token = getAuthToken($my_acc);
$test       = email_New_Filter_Or_Label($auth_token, "label");
// $test        = email_New_Filter_Or_Label($auth_token, "filter");

var_dump($test);
?>
```

---

Login does work just fine, but creating a label return a **500 error**. Running `php /my-script/path/public_html/my-script.php` via putty gives me this output:

```
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:805::1012... * connected
* Connected to www.google.com (2a00:1450:4001:805::1012) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=www.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Sep 10 13:49:36 2014 GMT
*       expire date: Dec 09 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*       common name: www.google.com
*       issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> POST /accounts/ClientLogin HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 476
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------6f31c3e84eeb

* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 23:22:35 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Length: 1139
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.002
<
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* About to connect() to apps-apis.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4010:c04::76... * connected
* Connected to apps-apis.google.com (2a00:1450:4010:c04::76) port 443 (#0)
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Sep 10 14:03:47 2014 GMT
*       expire date: Dec 09 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*       common name: *.google.com
*       issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> POST /a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/my-domain.com/super-admin/label HTTP/1.1
Host: apps-apis.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="DQAAAA8BAABE0TPBcstbG31ry47v9WUzihACSe6j11mMXTMNMiiFN09vtCqbMFr0lv_Y2tPJtavYyJdcI0mGsJLJDuC1_q15q6FgdNbO-mAPfOEg4Q8ybk4V_8CUSQNBFSUByC_CAfbwR2gWMw10wqfo9S8afU0LOfX4PrOAWnpA8Dy-3ZMJi-EkipLZlsehZTuW0WS3zkml1uYHTczYRyyH28Ns27ql8OtCW8KOmxvdgpWGYGAR20Z1kbqj3TUBGwE2j4r37qc25_Lj9sjdczmMuBZT8Fr_8SQSzcQaB_U08_NJcueaY4eUoSJfouxh_OqOjE5OTgrqywIzXDEO5K3kNP3o7egmj4p_p2s3k6ZVl2eowhYVqg"
Content-type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: 201

* The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
* Closing connection #0
bool(false)
```

I've spent the whole trying to make this work, I googled a lot (all in vain), can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, 500 errors mean it's something bad on Google's end (network issue or bug with the API). Have you tried reproducing the same issue on the Oauth Playgound (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) with the account your using on Apps?

Comment: @atmercy thanks, I tried the OAuth Playground and it worked just fine, labels were created properly. Obviously there's something wrong with my PHP code, I just can't figure out what is it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to properly(?) create a label and filter using this code (let's call it `email-api.php`):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'consts.php';

global $username, $google_app_domain, $user_email, $label_dir;
global $client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri, $developer_key, $app_name;

$action         = $_GET['action'];
if ( ($action !== NEW_LABEL) && ($action !== NEW_FILTER) && ($action !== NEW_LABEL_FILTER) ) { die('Error #1'); }

$email_label    = trim( $_GET['label'] );       // TODO: Sanitize passed data!


session_start();

set_include_path(GOOGLE_API_PHP_CLIENT_SRC . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';


/* =========================
  Use OAuth2 to authenticate
  ======================== */

$client       = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setApplicationName($app_name);
$client->setDeveloperKey($developer_key);
// $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify");
$client->addScope("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/");
$client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");

$service      = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
    {
        echo "Access Token expired :(<br />\n";
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
}
else
{
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { die("Invalid Access Token :(\n<br />"); }


/* =========================================================
  We're signed in so let's proceed with the specified action
 ========================================================= */

$authObj   = json_decode( $client->getAccessToken() );

switch ($action)
{
    case NEW_LABEL:
        DoURL( $google_app_domain, $username, NEW_LABEL,  GetData(NEW_LABEL) );
        break;

    case NEW_FILTER:
        DoURL( $google_app_domain, $username, NEW_FILTER, GetData(NEW_FILTER) );
        break;

    case NEW_LABEL_FILTER:
        DoURL( $google_app_domain, $username, NEW_LABEL,  GetData(NEW_LABEL) );
        DoURL( $google_app_domain, $username, NEW_FILTER, GetData(NEW_FILTER) );

        break;
}

// ============================================================== //
function GetData($action)
{
    global $username, $email_label, $label_dir, $google_app_domain;

    if ($action == NEW_LABEL)
    {
        $data  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
                        <apps:property name="label" value="' . $email_label . '" />
                    </atom:entry>';
    }
    else if ($action == NEW_FILTER)
    {
        $data  = "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>";
        $data .= "    <apps:property name='to' value='$username+$email_label@$google_app_domain' />";
        $data .= "    <apps:property name='label' value='$label_dir/$email_label' />";
        $data .= "    <apps:property name='neverSpam' value='true' />";
        $data .= "</atom:entry>";
    }

    return $data;
}

// ============================================================== //
function DoURL($google_app_domain, $username, $action, $data)
{
    global $authObj;

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/atom+xml",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($data),
        "Authorization: "  . $authObj->token_type . " " . $authObj->access_token,
        "X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST"
    );

    $ch      = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/$google_app_domain/$username/$action");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $data);

    print_r($response = curl_exec($ch));
}
// ============================================================== //
?>
```

This file needs another file (`consts.php`), which looks like this:

```
<?php
// =====================
// Constants
// =====================

define('GOOGLE_API_PHP_CLIENT_SRC', '/full/path/to/google-api-php-client/src/');

define('NEW_LABEL',        'label');
define('NEW_FILTER',       'filter');
define('NEW_LABEL_FILTER', 'both');

$username          = 'john.doe';
$google_app_domain = "super-domain.com";
$user_email        = "$username@$google_app_domain";

$client_id         = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret     = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';

// $redirect_uri should point to the main PHP file. Register a projet in https://console.developers.google.com/ and make sure redirect url points to this file, too
$redirect_uri      = "http://www.$google_app_domain/email-api.php";
$developer_key     = "AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$app_name          = 'Application name, as defined in https://console.developers.google.com/';

$label_dir         = 'Work';        // Optional, purely to organize mailbox, ie.        "Work/Boss" or "Work/HR", etc...
?>
```

I basically switched to OAuth2, refactored my code, made a lot of cleanup and...it seems to be working just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend utilizing the GMail API, which supports adding labels as well.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels